# Bounding the exponent in unit groups of modular group algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, finite-fields, p-groups, associativity

Let $p$ be a prime number, $G=:G_1$ a (non-Abelian) finite p-Group and $K$ a finite field with $\operatorname{char}(K)=p$. It is well-known that the group $G_2:=1+\operatorname{rad}(KG)$ is a p-group containing $G$. We can construct now $G_3:=1+\operatorname{rad}(KG_2)$ and so on. By this way can construct a sequence of p-groups with growing quantities.

My question is, whether the exponent of these groups  is bounded. As theses sequences are growing the bounding is equivalent to the fact that these exponents are getting constant after finite many steps.

Conjecture: The wreath product $\underbrace{C_p\wr ... \wr C_p}_{n-times}$ is involved in $G_n$.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this is the same question as bounding the nilpotency index of the augmentation ideal, right ?

Comment: No, if you consider the sequence of growing p-groups I want to know whether the exponent of these groups resp. the exponent of the centers of these groups is bounded.

Comment: Yes of course, but the exponent of $G_2$ for instance is the same as the nilpotency index of the augmentation ideal of $KG_1$

Comment: Hi Max, can you quote this result, please or present the argumenation for this? KR Sven

Comment: Well $ I(G) \subset KG $ is nilpotent (with nilpotency index a power of $ p $ )  when the characteristic is $ p $ and $ G $ is a $ p $ -  group. If $ x \in I(G) $ and $ x^{p^k}=0 $, then $ (1+x)^{p^l} = 1+x^{p^l}$ so it's $ 1 $ if and only if $ k \leq l $

Comment: Yes, so the exponent is bounded by the associative nilpotency index of the augmentation ideal becuase the class is not the maximal class of its elements.

Comment: Right, yes, sorry, that's what I meant

Comment: But then I will look if this is bounded maybe its a good starting point. There a several articles of Matose for this associative nilpotency class.

Comment: So trying to bound the exponent by the associative nlpotency index is not working: the associative would bound the Lie nilpotency index. By a theorem of Khripta this class is growing except in the case $p=2$ and the derived subgroup is of order 2. So we would have the situation that the derived subgroups of two members coincide if the index would be bounded. But this would imply that the groups are abelian. Abelian p-groups are excluded here because then the answer is clear.

Comment: So bounding the exponent by bounding it with the associative or Lie nilpotency class is not working.

Comment: But wait isn't the exponent of the group $G_{n+1}$ precisely the associative nilpotency index of $I(G_n)$ ? Therefore if it isn't bounded, so isn't the exponent

Comment: You may be interested in [Lie Dimension Subgroups, Lie Nilpotency Indices, and the Exponent of the Group of Normalized Units](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3191587/bounding-the-exponent-in-unit-groups-of-modular-group-algebras) by Aner Shalev

Comment: Thanks Alexander!

Comment: Have you looked at Jennings' theorem?

Comment: No I have not until now. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @Max: The exponent is not graeter as the maximum of all nilpotency indicies of all elements of the augmentation ideal. And this maximum is not greater as the associative nilpotency index of the augmentation ideal. But why should all of them be identical?

Comment: I found an argument to show that the exponent is not bounded and presented it in my little book https://www.anchor-publishing.com/document/511467 about On unit groups of modular group algebras in the last chapter. The question about involving the wreath product is still open.